# Why css\html code is behaving in a different way in differents hosts?

Tags: html, css

I've just edit one page, and in my local computer its get perfect. I made the things in such way that the navigation menu still in a position in with it got a good look in contrast to the background image (transparent navigation background, with black characters over a part of the background menu where it is white). It's looking like this in my local machine: 
[image: printscreen local machine]

But when I send it to remote servers, it get ugly, in unless two different ways, as follow:

- [This first](http://www.cruzbranca.com/), ugly, and;
- [This 2dn](http://igreja.altervista.org/CBCN/index.html), even more ugly.

What could be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off - The second host is using an extra  element, probably for tracking, or alike, which causes your style for div-elements, to apply to that aswell. You should use specific id's or classes for your elements, instead of just "div". Especially with "background"-properties.

You could solve this by adding following:

```
--some code--
<body><div><header></header>
--rest of the code
```

To

```
--some code--
<body><div id="container"><header></header>
--rest of the code
```

And changing in style.css: `div {....`to `div#container {....`

In my browser, the first link looks like your image, as it should, aswell.

Comment: As @Frederik mentions, your css needs to be more specific, and I also see the first link load just fine on Chrome and FF.